# CSS how is width getting set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have inherited a web page that has a slide show on it and I can't figure out how to change the width of the `<article>` containing the slide show.  I think it is getting size via JavaScript, but I have searched and can't figure out where.

If you view source on the page you will not see a width in the article tag, but if you use firebug to look at the styles you will see:

```css
element.style {
  width: 565px;
}
```

I've posted a sample version here: http://208.112.58.198/help/index_new.htm.

Comment: I see now that slide show width is responsive and cascading from a parent element.  The goal is to make the slide show full screen width and I still can't see why it's not filling the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your element's CSS width is being applied by the [jquery plugin](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel).

`/help/wp-content/themes/Cobalt3/cobalt/js/main68b3.js` this file line number #339 has the following code.

```
$('#part-slideshow').carouFredSel({
    height: 300,
    width: '100%',
    circular: true,
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        height: 300,
    },
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        fx: "crossfade",
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "swing"
    },
    auto: {
        timeoutDuration: 5000,
        delay: 5000,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    pagination: '#pagination',
    swipe: {
        onTouch: true,
        onMouse: true
    },
    responsive: true
});
```

The plugin binds a `resize` event function to the carousel elements, which sets the element width responsive to the screen size because `responsive: true` option is added in the call.